# Permission Denied in Hudson

Tags: ubuntu, hudson

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 lts and i mounted windows share drive in it. I want to make new directory in that share drive to copy my build binaries. When i build through hudson i am getting the following error message.

- mkdir dev
  mkdir : cannot create directory 'dev' : permission denied.
  Finished : Failure.

But when i use the terminal i can able to create the "dev" directory in that windows share drive. I tried with chmod 777 -R to give the permission to that share drive. it shows 
"chmod: changing permission of "/home/document/sharedrive" :permission denied.

pls help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can you write on mouted share outside hudson? Is share owner the same who mount?

Comment: I integrated the script inside hudson to make directory in windows share. yes the share owner is same who mount it into linux.

Answer (score 0):

run whoami command from Jenkins. Perhaps Jenkins user is not root and have no permissions.

Comment: You should run it not from terminal but from Jenkins to see output in jenkins job log